# computing multiple fixed effects on large dataset

Tags: r, regression, fixed, effects, ff

I'm trying to perform a fixed effects regression for two factor variables in a CSV dataset containing over 4000000 rows. These variables can respectively assume about 140000 and 50000 different integer values.

I initially attempted to perform the regression using the biglm and ff packages for R as follows on a Linux machine with 8 Gb of memory; however, it seems that this requires too much memory because R complains about having to allocate a vector of a size greater than the maximum on my machine.

```
library(biglm)
library(ff)
d <- read.csv.ffdf(file='data.csv', header=TRUE)
model = y~factor(a)+factor(b)-1
out <- biglm(model, data=d)
```

Some research online revealed that since factors are loaded into memory by ff, the latter will not significantly improve memory usage if many factor values are present.

Is anyone aware of some other way to perform the aforementioned regression on a dataset of the magnitude I described without having to resort to a machine with significantly more memory?

Comment: I would try to remove all other datasets / objects from R (also close all other projects), if there are any. You can do that by using rm() and after that gc() to release the clear data back to memory.

Comment: I did make sure that the above script was the only code run in the R session. In any case, I found that running the script on a machine with more (32 Gb) memory prevented the initial memory complaint but rapidly caused the machine to start using swap memory and slow down.

Comment: You currently have used biglm. I think you want to use bigglm with gaussian link. You should use bigglm.ffdf from package ffbase. require(ffbase) and methods(bigglm) gets you there. You also don't need to specify factor(a), a is already a factor.

Comment: Thanks for the bigglm pointer. Although it does work for a toy example, bigglm.ffdf returns a "model matrices incompatible" error when I use it with the ffdf object created from the CSV dataset. What could be causing this error?

Also, I'm not sure why factor(a) isn't necessary; even if the 'a' column in the dataset contains integers, isn't factor() needed to tell R not to simply treat it as a constant non-factor value? (At least that what seems to be the case using the toy example alluded to earlier.)

Comment: Ok, it looks like you have a real integer and you want to model it as a factor. In that case, you need to create a factor before doing biglm as this allows ff to know all the factor levels. So do something like d$a.as.factor <- as.character(d$a) and use model = y ~ a.as.factor + ...

Comment: I tried creating the factors before running bigglm (with d containing the ffdf created using read.csv.ffdf()), but ran into the "cannot allocate vector of size XX Gb" again: `d$a.as.factor <- as.character(d$a); d$b.as.factor <- as.character(d$b); out <- bigglm.ffdf(y~a.as.factor+b.as.factor-1, d)`

Comment: How many levels does a.as.factor and b.as.factor have?

Comment: 140000 and 50000, respectively.

Comment: Note also (as indicated in my comment to the answer by Elad663) that my goal is to compute the fixed effects themselves, not simply to estimate the coefficients.

Comment: I think you just have **too many levels** to fit in your model. You might not even have enough data to reliably fit this model. Internally bigglm.ffdf does something like model.matrix on a chunk of your dataset. The default chunksize is 5000 rows, but you can even lower this to overcome the memory barrier (see ?bigglm.ffdf). But do you really want to fit this model with 190000 parameters in the model????????

Comment: The nature of the data is such that it's plausible to suspect that the results of the regression may say something interesting about how the two fixed effects affect the endogenous variables despite the large number of parameters. Of course, if the computation is just too computationally demanding given the resources at my disposal, I'll have to cut down the size of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should try the package lfe, it has been designed for exactly this purpose:

```
library(lfe)
...
out <- felm(y ~ 0|a+b, data=d)
fe <- getfe(out)
```

A proof of the method can be found here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947313001266

Here's an R-journal article about it: http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-2/gaure.pdf

Comment: I tried lfe, but the dataset was still too large to handle on my system.

Comment: Ok, then it's not the number of levels in the factor which is the problem, but your handling of the dataset. It contains 4 million rows, with two factors in each. Factors use 4-byte int storage, so 8 bytes per row, that's a mere 32MB.  lfe will make two copies (one for the model matrix (which is empty if the factors are the only covariates), and one for the result, you'll stay under 100MB, well under 8GB.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the same mathematical meaning of fixed effects if you will demean the variables (by category). So, instead of finding a constant per dummy, you demean it. and demeaning will be very fast, as it is will be vectorized.

Edit1:
see Green 2012 p.400-401 for the mathematical proof.

Comment: Sorry - what is the full reference for the proof?

I may not have been sufficiently clear in my original post, but my goal is to determine the values of the fixed effects. Although I follow that demeaning the data w.r.t. each of the fixed effects will allow one to perform an equivalent regression, how can one use it to obtain the actual fixed effects themselves? (More references welcome.)

Comment: @lebedov Sorry for the delay, I missed this notification. I did not understand that you are interested in the FE themselves. I thought this was only a performance issue.

Comment: But "demeaning = fixed effects" only works for linear models.

Comment: @hansonhill of course, the question is not about a nonlinear model

Comment: Also, when regression with demeaned variables, the standard errors will be wrong, i.e. lower.